# JsonPatchDocument applyTo() not using all of the properties, why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, axios, json-patch

When I call applyTo() on a JsonPatchDocument and then save changes the query that EF runs only uses the recordId, coworkerId and startDate to update. It's **NOT** using the IsActive field/column! Why is that and without this condition I get a DbUpdateConcurrencyException because the number of rows are now more then 1.

```
    public static async Task<HttpResult> PatchRecordCoworkerAsync(MpidDbContext context, int id, JsonPatchDocument<RecordCoworker> patch)
    {
        // fetches a single row
        var recordCoworker = context.RecordsCoworkers.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id && m.IsActive == true);

        patch.ApplyTo(recordCoworker);

        try
        {
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        // exception says "Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 2 row(s)"
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
        }

        return HttpResult.NoContent;
    }
```

the query that gets run when applying the patch changes is

> SET NOCOUNT ON;
>   UPDATE [Records_Coworkers] SET [StartDate] = @p0
>   WHERE [RecordID] = @p1 AND [CoworkerID] = @p2 AND [StartDate] IS NULL;
>   SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

here is the model

```
[Table("Records_Coworkers")]
public class RecordCoworker
{
    public RecordCoworker()
    {
        IsActive = true;
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("Record_CoworkerID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("RecordID")]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public virtual Record Record { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("CoworkerID")]
    public int CoworkerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Coworker Coworker { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to configure somewthing differently so that the 'IsActive' property is used in the patch?

my axios call looks like this

```js
axios.patch('/api/RecordCoworkers/' + id, [{
  'op': 'replace',
  'path': '/startDate',
  'value': value,
}]).then(function(response) {
  // Show response
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Show error
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: How does `recordCoworker` looks like after you call `patch` on it? Did you debug to see if the `isActive` property is lost somehow?

Comment: when you say "call patch on it", you mean save the changes? because I don't think anything is run/queried until I save the changes. What I can say is that when I fetch the recordCoworker the IsActive field is there and correct!

Comment: What I meant was how `recordCoworker` looks like after you call `patch.ApplyTo(recordCoworker);` Clearly, the IsActive is being overwritten somehow after it.

Comment: looking at the query, I don't think it's being overwritten, it looks as if it's being removed all together! From the sql query that is..How is that even possible?

Comment: Did you override SaveChanges? There’s no much going on to set a different value to it from the code you showed so..